# Java stream - verify at least one element in a list contains in another

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a Map. Let's say

```
Map<Long, Train>
```

Each Train has a list

```
List<Integer> parts = train.getTrainParts()
```

I have another list

```
List<Integer> blueParts;
```

I want to iterate the map and collect all trains that have at least one blue part.

This is a naive usage of `Stream`s :

```
trainMap().values().stream().filter(part -> {
     boolean found = false;
     for (Long part : train.getTrainParts()) {
         if (blueParts.conatins(part)) {
              found = true;
         }
     }
     return found;
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What are better options ? 
Stream or not stream?

e.g.

```
 tagDataContainer.getDeliveryGroupMap().values().stream().filter(dg -> {
                Sets.SetView<Long> intersection = Sets.intersection(Sets.newHashSet(dg.getPlacements()), Sets.newHashSet(placementsToChangeStatusToPublish));
                return intersection.size()>0;
       }
 );
```

Comment: Just wondering: "parts" are Integers? Interesting approach ;-)

Comment: It's an example. Ids points to parts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simplify the filter :

```
List<Train> = 
    trainMap().values()
              .stream()
              .filter(t-> t.getTrainParts().stream().anyMatch(p->blueParts.contains(p)))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And if you can change `blueParts` to be a `HashSet` instead of a `List`, your code would run faster, since `blueParts.contains()` would require constant time instead of linear time.

Comment: You may use `blueParts::contains` as predicate. If these `Integer`s stem from a range of consecutive values (as IDs usually do), you may also consider using a `BitSet` instead of a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 1):

based on your question: "I want to iterate the map and collect all trains that have at least one blue part." i think you are looking for trains that have atleast one element in bluepart list, below is something you could do.

`List<Train> trainList =  trainMap.values().stream().filter(t -> t.getBlueParts().size()>0).collect(Collectors.toList());`